# I need solution

Tags: web, web-applications

I need to make website application that makes calculation on client side but do not know how to make this!? Calculations on client side takes about one minute. When I use JavaScript for loop it freeze browser and anyone can see my code. Also when I use Python it`s run on server side and it is not solution for many connections.

Answer (score 0):

Client Side and working in different browsers without Plugins, you are pretty much limited to Javascript, with all its (anti)features.

Your problem with a freezing browser sounds more like an infinite loop.
I would check your code again.